# how to go default calendar in android?

Tags: android

I am making calendar based app and I am trying to go to my application to default calendar and also searching on internet but i can't it so is it possible to open default calendar using intent advance in thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
PackageManager packmngr = this.getPackageManager(); 
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER); 
List<ResolveInfo> list = packmngr.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
ResolveInfo Resolvebest = null;
for (final ResolveInfo info : list){
if (info.activityInfo.packageName.endsWith(".calendar"))
        Resolvebest = info;
}
if (Resolvebest != null){
 intent.setClassName(Resolvebest.activityInfo.packageName,
 Resolvebest.activityInfo.name);
 startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);  
intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
intent.putExtra("title", "Some title");
intent.putExtra("description", "Some description");
intent.putExtra("beginTime", eventStartInMillis);
intent.putExtra("endTime", eventEndInMillis);
startActivity(intent);
```

The documentation is found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#intents)